# How to do AOP with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aop

I have a little problem doing some AOP with node.js:
Let's say I have an application in a script called *server.js*, and I want to monitor its functions.

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Home');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    login(req,res);
    module.exports.login_(req, res);
});
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send(404, 'Page introuvable !');
});

function login(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Page de login');
}

app.listen(1616);
```

As you can see, I want to monitor the unique function *login(req, res)*. In order to do this, I want to use AOP within another script, but all I can find - and I think it is due to the nature of the Javascript language - implies a lot of code intrusion.

Is there any way to do AOP just like in Spring/Java? Without having to do any code intrusion?

Currently, my solution is this one: 
*Here is our application with some code-intrusion*

```
    var express = require('express');

    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('Home');
    });

    app.get('/login', function(req, res){

        //We need to use the function in module.exports
                    //--> code intrusion
        //login(req,res);
        module.exports.login_(req, res);
    });


    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.send(404, 'Page introuvable !');
    });


    function login(req, res){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('Page de login');
    }

    //We wrap here the function we want to monitor
    wrappedLogin = function(req, res){
        login(req, res);
    }

    module.exports = {
        login_ : wrappedLogin
    };


    app.listen(1616);
```

*And here is our AOP script*

```
var aop = require("node-aop");

//Include the server
var server = require('./server.js');


aop.before(server, "login_", function(key, value){
        //I do some stuff here
});


aop.after(server, "login_", function(key, value){
        //I do some stuff here
});
```

And finally, all I have to do is

```
node aop.js
```

It works, but as you can see, there is some code intrusion. And I want to get rid of it. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 9):

> I think it is due to the nature of the Javascript language - implies a
>   lot of code intrusion.

please don't :'(

**AOP is an extension of OOP, there is no AOP without OOP.**

I suggest you to use [kaop](https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop) or TS version with ES7 decorators [kaop-ts](https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop-ts/)

1º: `npm install kaop --save`

2º: define an advice to monitor your methods:

```
import { reflect } from "kaop"

const Log = reflect.advice(meta => {
  //meta.args contains the arguments {array}
   console.log(meta.methodName + " called");
   console.log("with arguments: " + meta.args);
   console.log("returned: " + meta.result);
})
```

3º you have to organize your code following OOP guidelines:

```
const Controller = createClass({
  constructor: function(app){
    app.get('/', this.home);
    app.get('/login', this.login);
    app.use(this.notFound);
  },
  login: [function(req, res){
    //what ever
  }, Log],
  home: [function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Home');
  }, Log],
  notFound: [function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send(404, 'Page introuvable !');
  }, Log]
})
```

I've writed an [article](https://dev.to/k1r0s/idiomatic-javascript-backend-part-1-4g0b) on 2018 which discuss AOP on JS server side.

Comment: Would this also work for javascript files written like `(function(){var Foo = function(args) {/*...*/};Foo.prototype.bar = function(args){/*...*/};exports.Foo = Foo;})();`? This is how the current codebase i am looking at is constructed, and i can not change it. I would also be interested in how this can be logged into a file, because – i guess we all agree – logging to the console in Node.js is not a pleasant experience, especially when logging objects which have references to parent objects ...

Comment: I guess you can extend https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop/#get-started

Answer (score 4):

To avoid reinventing the wheel, you could use nestjs which is a framework that propose a lot of tools. Among them you'll find interceptors which do what you want (i think).

https://nestjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

A naive attempt would look something like this.

```
var before = function(object, functionName, action) {
  var oldFunction = object.functionName;
  var newFunction = function() {
    action();
    oldFunction();
  };
  object.functionName = oldFunction;
}

var after = function(object, functionName, action) {
  var fn = object.functionName;
  var after = function() {
    fn();
    action();
  };
  object.functionName = oldFunction;
}
```

JS is very flexible; you could easily improve on this by storing the after and before actions and adding/removing them as required, but at the very least this should do what you want (albeit not in a very good manner).

Comment: I actually found a solution (very basic). You can found it here : [node-bakery](https://github.com/nugetchar/node-bakery)

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of [@aspectjs](https://github.com/NicolasThierion/aspectjs). I recently created this lib to offer way to achieve AOP with the help of ES decorators, inspired by the java library AspectJ library.

I tested it with a `@Log()` decorator that do exactly what you want.
I know this topic is a little old, but may be useful for others in the future.