# Winston logger.log(). How do I grab parameters from logger function?

Tags: javascript, logging, speech-to-text, winston, watson

I am currently working with Watson Conversation service and had a question concerning one of the npm modules utilized in their service.
My problem is passing speech to text input from a user as the argument for a function I am running.
From what I have found on my own, the program logs all info obtained from speech to text with the Winston npm package. There is a function

```
logger.log('info', 'test message %s', 'my string');
```

[See Winston documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)

The output to the terminal from speech to text is...

```
info: myString
```

I have a terminal program written that takes the user's input as an argument for a weather function.
However, the function is never called because I assume it is looking for an 'enter' keystrike in the terminal (I am using npm readline for this).

Is there a way to access the arguments from the Winston `logger.log()` function and simply grab the `myString` text from the most recent `logger.log` call and save it as a variable?
Then pass that variable as an argument to my function?
I am thinking I could bypass even needing to use `readline.createInterface();` in order to capture user input.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like [aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) stuff.  Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304146/how-to-do-aop-with-node-js) could be useful to you ; especially the answer from k1r0s about the [kaop package](https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop).

Comment: It's hard to help you without more context. You could add a fiddle, maybe? You may try to implement the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It would allow you to add behavior as method calls.